# (3 Parts) Fixed Background, Other Elements Scrolling

Tags: java, image, swing, background

Sorry for such a stupid question, but I'm having some trouble setting my background image in Java on a fixed image. Here's what I mean -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class MainFrame{

public static void createGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Warlords Organizer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    JLabel contentPane = new JLabel();
    contentPane.setIcon(/imageFolder/warlordsOrganizerBackground.png);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createGUI();
        }
    });
} // public static void main(String[] args) Closing
} // public class MainFrame Closing
```

So I can get the frame, and everything like that, but I can't seem to load the image. I put the image in a source folder named imageFolder -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShPLs.png

[image]

And finally, how can I make the background image to where when I scroll down, the image stays in the same place, but the text and other images I plan on adding move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
contentPane.setIcon(/imageFolder/warlordsOrganizerBackground.png); // ????
```

- You must pass an Icon object to your `setIcon(...)` method. I'm not sure what you're passing in there, but it looks like a String without quotes.
- You're adding components to a container, the contentPane, and then promptly swapping out this container for another. This will make it so that you shouldn't see any of the components added to the lame-duck component (the old contentPane).
- The solution is obvious: add components to the contentPane that is eventually displayed.
- Also make sure to give the JLabel a decent layout manager as well.
- To scroll over the image, place add a JScrollPane on your JLabel/contentPane but make the JScrollPane and its JViewPort non-opaque.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame {

   private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "imgFolder/ham-hamster.jpg";

   public static void createGUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fubars");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      File imageFile = new File(IMAGE_PATH);
      try {
         JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
         textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         textArea.setLineWrap(true);
         for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            textArea.append("foo bars rule the world!\n");
         }
         textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20));
         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
         scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
         scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

         textArea.setOpaque(false);
         scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
         scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

         BufferedImage backgroundImg = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
         Icon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(backgroundImg);
         JLabel contentLabel = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);
         contentLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         contentLabel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         frame.setContentPane(contentLabel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

Comment: +1, I like the using the label as the container for the scrollpane since the frame is not resizable.

Comment: Wow, this is really good. First, it was a string without quotes, what a stupid mistake on my part. I also forgot that I didn't use the old contentPane. The main part I didn't understand with your code is the JScrollPane. I'll read up on that now. And finally, what is the e.printStackTrace(); ?

Comment: @Hathor: the `e.printStackTrace()` prints out any messages from the exception to the standard error output.

Answer (score 3):

See [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for examples of how to load an image.

If you ever need to use a scaled image as a background then you can use the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). It will set the scrollpane and the viewport non-opaque for you when.